# Searching a list

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to have a user input then the program will search the array to see if the input animal is in the array. If it is in the array it should print out

```
" String " + animal + " was found using " + compCount + " comparisions. "
```

and if it isn't it should print out

```
" String " + animal + " could not be found, and " + compCount + " comparisons were performed. "
```

I am having problems with the else statement and every time it isn't stopping once it finds the word. Any suggestions?

```
public class AnimalSearch
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] A = {"cat", "dog", "mouse", "fox", "bear", "wolf", "eagle", "moose", "parrot", "rabbit"};
        
        String animal = (args[0]);
        
        for (int compCount = 1; compCount <= A.length; compCount++)
        {
            if (A.equals(animal)) break;
            System.out.println(" String " + animal + " was found using " + compCount + " comparisions. ");
            
            else
                System.out.println(" String " + animal + " could not be found, and " + compCount + " comparisons were performed. ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't even compile. That `else` isn't matched with an `if`. Is that `break` and the `println()` immediately following it actually there in your code?

Comment: I think the for loop should start at 0 and go to compCount < A.length

Comment: @PeterMaxwell not necessarily, as he would have to alter his println later in that case.

Comment: @user2310289 True, but actually he should be using `A[compCount].equals(animal)` in which case he would need to do it that way. Otherwise he's comparing the array object itself. Or he could do `A[compCount-1].equals(animal)`. As I now see you have just explained below.

Answer (score 6):

You are comparing the whole array `A` with the string.

try comparing the individual elements.

```
if (A[compCount -1].equals(animal)) {
  System.out.println("String " + animal + " was found using " + compCount + " comparisions.");
  break;
 }
```

Also note that you should `break` after printing.

Also it would be better still to use equalsIgnoreCase

Comment: You don't necessarily need to `break` after printing if the `if...else` is the only thing in the loop (or if there is other common code that should execute afterwards).

Comment: don't necessarily need, but an early termination is often good.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
String[] A = {"cat", "dog", "mouse", "fox", "bear", "wolf", "eagle", "moose", "parrot", "rabbit"};
String animal = (args[0]);

if(Arrays.asList(A).contains(animal))
   {
      System.out.println(" String " + animal + " was found using " + compCount + " comparisions. ");
   }
   else
   {
      System.out.println(" String " + animal + " could not be found, and " + compCount + " comparisons were performed. ");
   }
```

Comment: This still has the issue of comparing the entire array `A` with the string.